# Assigning column name as title within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, r-colnames

I am attempting to make a plots for each column of my dataframe and pass on the column name to be the title for each plot. There are a total of 72 columns that need their own individual plot. Facet_wrap is not an appropriate solution to this problem.

Running the top code gives me the individual plots with the incorrect name. This returns the first row value from i column. I want to return the column name.
[plot with first row value for name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z70RW.png)

Is there a way I can automatically pull column names into the title for each iteration?

Here is my subset of my data

```
Wisconsin_GR <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Species   Adams    Ashland    Barron    Bayfield    Brown
  Ash    -.5889    4.1211    5.6036    26.8347    NA
  Aspen    -.5867    15.82    .4329    1.1622    NA
")
```

The code that returns a plot with the first row value of i column.

```
    for( i in Wisconsin_GR[2:6]){
      print(
      gf_point(i~Species, data = test)%>% 
      gf_labs(title=i,
        y = "Growth to Removal Ratio",
        x = "")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limit = c(-5,100)))
}
```

The code below is altered to pull column names which works fine for the call names(Wisconsin_GR) but returns the following error when input into the code.

Error:
x Can't convert from  to  due to loss of precision.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't convert from  to  due to loss of precision.

```
    for( i in Wisconsin_GR[2:6]){
      print(
      gf_point(i~Species, data = test)%>% 
      gf_labs(title=names(Wisconsin_GR[i]),
        y = "Growth to Removal Ratio",
        x = "")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limit = c(-5,100)))
}
```

Comment: Where is `gf_point` from? Can you please declare your packages?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggformula/versions/0.10.1/topics/gf_point   Its from ggformula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how many rows of data you have, because this code is not fast, but works.

Note the if condition I added, that might be problematic but not too complicated to deal with.

And it's always better to state where your data is from (it's from `ggformula`, but we don't need to check ourselves).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

Wisconsin_GR <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Species   Adams    Ashland    Barron    Bayfield    Brown
  Ash    -.5889    4.1211    5.6036    26.8347    NA
  Aspen    -.5867    15.82    .4329    1.1622    NA
")
# First let us create a name column

names_to_plot <- colnames(Wisconsin_GR)

# Now that we have the name, we can start our loop.
for(i.tmp in 2:6){
  
  # Pick a a title for the plot from each colname of the data
  tmp.title <- names_to_plot[i.tmp]
  
  # Pick what to plot on the x axis and also the values for each colname.
  tmp.xaxis <- Wisconsin_GR %>%
    select(glue("{names_to_plot[c(1,i.tmp)]}")) %>% 
    pull(glue("{names_to_plot[1]}"))
  
  tmp.values <- Wisconsin_GR %>%
    select(glue("{names_to_plot[c(1,i.tmp)]}")) %>% 
    pull(glue("{names_to_plot[i.tmp]}"))
  
  # Now unite the three temporary variables into one single temporary data frame
  tmp.df <- data.frame(
    col_title=tmp.title,
    Species=tmp.xaxis,
    values=tmp.values
  )
  
  # The condition is added since when NA values are to be plotted, it distrupts ggplot's behaviour.
  # If you don't want to skip on plotting NA values,
  # You can modify the aes(x=..) to 1:length(Species),
  # and add scale_x_continuous(labels = tmp.df$Species,
  #                          breaks = 1:length(tmp.df$Species))
  if(is.na(tmp.df$values[1])){next}
  
  # With this tmp data frame we can now plot each figure
  print(
    tmp.df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Species,y=values))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(title=glue("Column: {tmp.df$col_title[1]}"))+
      ylab("Growth to Removal Ratio")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limit = c(-5,100))
  )
}

# Get rid of all these nasty tmp variables, they are no longer needed.
rm(list =ls(pattern = "tmp"))
```